# Why are h264/ac3/mkv videos showing up as "motion jpeg" with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, video-conversion

I use xmedia recode, which uses ffmpeg, to convert these videos using "copy" video and "convert" ac3 -> aac, with an mp4 container. For most videos this works fine, and is really fast. However some show up as "motion jpeg", and when I convert them I'm given a small file with the audio and a black screen. In VLC they show up as h264/ac3 under codec information.

I tried tencoder with ffmpeg and got the same results. However if I switch the tencoder's encoder to mencoder, the videos come out fine. The problem is they take 30 minutes each, whereas ffmpeg copying in xmedia takes 2 minutes. Is there a way I can strip these videos of their "motion jpeg"-ness?

Here is the log:

```
Encoder 1 log
Encoder 1 command lines:
 -y  -itsoffset 0 -threads 8  -i "Z:\Downloads\3. Convert\test.mkv"     -c:v libx264  -crf 21   -level 41  -f mp4  -map 0:2 -map 0:1  -strict experimental -c:a aac -ab 320k  -af aresample=resampler=soxr -ar 44100 -ac 2    "Z:\Downloads\3. Convert\test.mp4"

Encoder 1 console outputs:
ffmpeg version N-71403-g415f1fa Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 22.101 / 54. 22.101
  libavcodec     56. 34.100 / 56. 34.100
  libavformat    56. 30.100 / 56. 30.100
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 13.101 /  5. 13.101
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'Z:\Downloads\3. Convert\test.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.3.0 + libmatroska v1.4.1
    creation_time   : 2015-01-16 07:42:24
  Duration: 00:20:18.47, start: 0.083000, bitrate: 4818 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 2k tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Stream #0:2: Video: mjpeg, yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 340x340 [SAR 300:300 DAR 1:1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      filename        : cover.jpeg
      mimetype        : image/jpeg
[mp4 @ 00000000027008e0] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.
Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2
No pixel format specified, yuvj444p for H.264 encoding chosen.
Use -pix_fmt yuv420p for compatibility with outdated media players.
[libx264 @ 0000000003d4f020] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0000000003d4f020] MB rate (43560000) > level limit (245760)
[libx264 @ 0000000003d4f020] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX XOP FMA4 FMA3 LZCNT BMI1
[libx264 @ 0000000003d4f020] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 4.1, 4:4:4 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0000000003d4f020] 264 - core 146 r2538 121396c - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=21.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'Z:\Downloads\3. Convert\test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.30.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuvj444p(pc), 340x340 [SAR 300:300 DAR 1:1], q=-1--1, 90k fps, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      filename        : cover.jpeg
      mimetype        : image/jpeg
      encoder         : Lavc56.34.100 libx264
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc56.34.100 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=31.0 Lsize=   47681kB time=00:20:18.40 bitrate= 320.6kbits/s    
video:10kB audio:47281kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.825254%
[libx264 @ 0000000003d4f020] frame I:1     Avg QP:31.31  size:  9546
[libx264 @ 0000000003d4f020] mb I  I16..4:  7.0% 77.1% 15.9%
[libx264 @ 0000000003d4f020] 8x8 transform intra:77.1%
[libx264 @ 0000000003d4f020] coded y,u,v intra: 48.1% 11.9% 10.3%
[libx264 @ 0000000003d4f020] i16 v,h,dc,p: 12% 21% 21% 47%
[libx264 @ 0000000003d4f020] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 32%  9% 32%  3%  4%  5%  4%  5%  6%
[libx264 @ 0000000003d4f020] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23%  9% 21%  8%  7% 10%  6% 10%  6%
[libx264 @ 0000000003d4f020] kb/s:6873120.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The problem

The issue is your usage of `-map`. You're telling `ffmpeg` to map steams  `0:2` and `0:1` which in this input correspond to the `aac` audio stream and the `mjpeg` video stream.

## Solutions

### Use the default stream selection

You can omit the `-map` options and rely on the default [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) behavior:

> By default, `ffmpeg` includes only one stream of each type (video,
>   audio, subtitle) present in the input files and adds them to each
>   output file. It picks the "best" of each based upon the following
>   criteria:
>
> - video – the stream with the highest resolution
> - audio – the stream with the most channels
> - subtitles – the first subtitle stream
>
> In the case where several streams of the same type rate equally, the
>   stream with the lowest index is chosen.

### Use proper mapping

If the default stream selection is not acceptable for you then you'll have to use the correct `-map` options for each input.

A better method than explicitly selecting a particular stream by index number is to add a stream specifier.

#### Examples

1. Choose all video streams and all audio streams from the first (and only) input:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i input0 -map 0:v -map 0:a … output
   ```

   - Note that `ffmpeg` starts counting from 0.
2. Choose the first video stream from the second input and the third audio stream from the first input:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -map 1:v:0 -map 0:a:2 … output
   ```
3. Use a negative mapping to choose all streams from input 0 except any subtitle streams:

   ```
   ffmpeg -i input0 -map 0 -map -0:s … output
   ```

## Also see

- [`-map` documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options)
- [FFmpeg mux video and audio (from another video) - mapping issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12943003/1109017)
- [ffmpeg, how to add new audio (not mixing) in video](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11783474/1109017)

Answer (score 0):

Open the mkv in mkvmerge, check if it has attachments and if it does, remove them, mux and try converting again.
Attachments is the only thing I have encountered that cause an mkv to display as "motion jpeg" in Xmedia recode.